# Android not picking up jQuery Mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-webview

i am loading a simple html file which uses html5 and jQuery mobile, the page is working fine on PC browser but when i put it in assets folder of my android app and load it in a WebView jQuery mobile tags do not work eg data-role, popups etc.

Here is my android activity code

```
WebView index = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
index.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

and here is the head tag of html page

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js\jquery.mobile-1.4.2\jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="js\jquery.mobile-1.4.2\jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script src="js\jquery.mobile-1.4.2\jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js\jquery.mobile-1.4.2\jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Html file in in root of asset folder and jQuery Mobile files are in `assets/jquery.mobile-1.4.2` folder

Comment: are you using phonegap or cordova to do so

Comment: no i am not using PhoneGap or Cordova . .

Comment: if not then you want to enable javascript on your activity page

Comment: WebSettings webSettings = index.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: add this line to your onCrete

Comment: you dont need this `js\jquery.mobile-1.4.2\jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS Ricky suggested the solution in comments , i needed to enable javascript on activity page so problem was solved by adding this line

```
WebSettings webSettings = index.getSettings(); webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on a JellyBean+ device, you need to put these lines:

```
WebSettings s = mWebView.getSettings();
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
        s.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        s.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }
```

To allow access to assets from your files.

Comment: what is "s" in s.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

Comment: sorry, that's the `WebSettings` object you get from your `WebView`

Comment: i have tried that but i am getting this eroor "The method setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(boolean) is undefined for the type WebSettings"  minSdkVersion and Targeted SDK Version of myy app is "8"

Comment: As I said, this affects devices with JellyBean and further. If you want to support these devices (which I'm sure you are interested in), you should work with the latest SDK even if you target SDK 8. That's why the two lines are surrounded by the platform check `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)`. Previous version of the SDK did not include these parameters.